# Giving priority to some lines in mysql while ordering

Tags: mysql

I have a "deals" table with "id", "name", "created_at" ... columns.
I have a "speciallisting_deal" pivot table which keeps relations between special lists and deals. Its columns are "id", "deal_id", "speciallisting_id" ... .

In my case, speciallisting_id is certain, let say 10. While getting results from "deals" table by according to some criteria (like ordering by created_at etc.), I want to give priority (I mean I want to see them at the top of results) to lines in "deals" which its id in this "(SELECT deal_id FROM speciallisting_deal WHERE speciallisting_id = 10)" or equivalent.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement in `order by`:

```
order by (case when specialist_id = 10 then 0 else 1 end),
         created_at desc
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple left join would likely suffice.  It really is better to provide what you tried to do yourself though.

```
SELECT

    d.id,
    d.name,
    d.created_at,
    -- Find out if this is considered "special"
    IF(sd.id IS NULL,0,1) AS isSpecial

FROM deals d

-- Left join the speciallistings onto this
LEFT JOIN speciallisting_deal sd
    ON sd.deal_id = d.id
    -- You don't have to specify a specific ID if you just want to get all that are special
    AND sd.speciallisting_id = 10
    -- You could do multiple speciallisting_id's using IN
    -- AND sd.speciallisting_id IN (8,2,10,314)

ORDER BY 
    isSpecial DESC, 
    d.created_at DESC
```